# UDP sockets and full-duplex audio issues

Tags: c, sockets, udp, alsa

The following code is part of a C-RAN program where the server code is part of a larger module code that serves as an interface to communicate with the Remote Radio Head.

To simplify it, let us treat it as a simple client-server service. The server will send an audio file through a specific UDP socket (port1) to the client and this one will play it back. Then, the client sends an ACK to the server through another socket (port2). Afterwards, the client starts recording audio and sends the datagrams via socket (port3). FInally, the client sends again a last ack through socket (port4).

Why so many different sockets? It is mandatory, full-duplex is a must, let's leave it here.

If I "comment" the code where the client records audio, communications between client-server are fine, audio is played back properly, no choppy playback. As soon as I activate the client code for recording, the playback starts to be choppy and the recording is a mess.

I've tried all sort of tests, like reducing the number of sockets, increasing the buffer sizes, removing one or all the acks, etc..

My network programming skills are so so, thus I don't know what else I can do. One thing is for sure, either there's a datagram flow issue or the ALSA lib drives can not cope, the latter I doubt it.

The way the code is in here, audio playback will be fine, all code parts for recording are commented in the client code.

Client:

```
//COMPILE: gcc -o client client.c -lasound
//EXECUTE (only playback): ./client
//EXECUTE (playback&recording): ./client > recordedFilename.raw

/*
-------- Remote Radio Head - client side

Remote Radio Head recieves audio from a dedicated socket from BBU, may process it or not
and sends audio through a different socket to the BBU.
*/
/* DEPENDENCIES */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
/* CONSTANTS */
#define PORT1            8070
#define PORT2            8080
#define PORT3            8090
#define PORT4            8100
#define MAXLINE          1024
#define FRAME_SIZE       512
#define PAYLOAD_SIZE     (FRAME_SIZE * 4)
/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

// START
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Sockets variables
    int                           sockfd1, sockfd2, sockfd3, sockfd4;
    int                           len, n;
    int                           i = 1;
    const char* ACK_play =        "playback_ack";
    const char* ACK_rec =         "recording_ack";
    const char* START_BROADCAST = "CLIENT: Connected !!!";
    const char* MSG =             "\nCLIENT: sending recording datagrams\n";
    char                          buffer[MAXLINE];

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr1, servaddr2, servaddr3, servaddr4;

    // ALSA playback variables
    int                 rc;
    int                 size;
    snd_pcm_t           *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    unsigned int        val;
    int                 dir;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t   frames;

    // ALSA recording variables
    long                loops;
    int                 rc2;
    int                 size2;
    snd_pcm_t           *handle2;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params2;
    unsigned int        val2;
    int                 dir2;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t   frames2;
    char                *buffer2;

    /*********************************************
    *      ALSA PLAYBACK DRIVERS SETUP           *
    *********************************************/
    // Open PCM device for playback.
    rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open pcm device: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
    }
    // Allocate a hardware parameters object.
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
    // Fill it in with default values.
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);
    // Set the desired hardware parameters.
    // Interleaved mode
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
    // Signed 16-bit little-endian format
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    // Two channels (stereo)
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);
    // playback sampling rate
    val = 48000;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);
    // Set period size to 32 frames.
    frames = FRAME_SIZE;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);
    // Write the parameters to the driver
    rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************************
    *       ALSA RECORDING DRIVERS SETUP         *
    *********************************************/
    // Open PCM device for recording (capture).
    rc2 = snd_pcm_open(&handle2, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
    if (rc2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open pcm device: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc2));
        exit(1);
    }
    // Allocate a hardware parameters object.
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params2);
    // Fill it in with default values.
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle2, params2);
    // Set the desired hardware parameters.
    // Interleaved mode
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle2, params2, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
    // Signed 16-bit little-endian format
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle2, params2, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    // Two channels (stereo)
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle2, params2, 2);
    // recording sampling rate
    val2 = 48000;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle2, params2, &val, &dir2);
    // Set period size to 32 frames.
    frames2 = FRAME_SIZE;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle2, params2, &frames, &dir2);

    // Write the parameters to the driver
    rc2 = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle2, params2);
    if (rc2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc2));
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************************
    *     CREATING SOCKET FILE DESCRIPTOR        *
    *********************************************/

    // --------------- SOCKET 1
    if ((sockfd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket 1 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr1, 0, sizeof(servaddr1));
    // Filling server 1 information
    servaddr1.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // ipv4
    servaddr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any server
    servaddr1.sin_port =        htons(PORT1);

    // --------------- SOCKET 2
    if ((sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket 2 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr2, 0, sizeof(servaddr2));
    // Filling server 2 information
    servaddr2.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // ipv4
    servaddr2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any server
    servaddr2.sin_port =        htons(PORT2);

    // --------------- SOCKET 3
    if ((sockfd3 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket 3 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr3, 0, sizeof(servaddr3));
    // Filling server 2 information
    servaddr3.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // ipv4
    servaddr3.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any server
    servaddr3.sin_port =        htons(PORT3);

    // --------------- SOCKET 4
    if ((sockfd4 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket 4 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr4, 0, sizeof(servaddr4));
    // Filling server 2 information
    servaddr4.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // ipv4
    servaddr4.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any server
    servaddr4.sin_port =        htons(PORT4);

    /********************************************
    *         SEND MSG TO SERVER                *
    ********************************************/
    //sockfd:       File descriptor of socket
    //buffer:       Application buffer cointaining the data to be sent
    //len:          Size of buffer
    //flags:        Bitwise OR flags to modify socket behaviour
    //dest_addr:    Structure containing address of destination
    //addrlen:      Size of dest_addr structure
    sendto(sockfd1, START_BROADCAST, strlen(START_BROADCAST), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr1, sizeof(servaddr1));
    printf("CLIENT: Waiting for audio!!!\n");

    /********************************************
    *         RECIEVE MSG FROM SERVER           *
    ********************************************/
    //sockfd:       file descriptor of socket
    //buffer:       Apllication buffer in which to recieve data
    //len:          Size of buffer
    //flags:        Bitwise OR flags to modify socket behaviour
    //src_addr:     Structure containing source address is returned
    //addrlen:      Variable in which size of src_addr structure is returned

    /* We allocate memory to store the payload of the incoming datagram. */
    char *play_load = (char *)malloc(PAYLOAD_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    char *rec_load = (char *)malloc(PAYLOAD_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /* HERE CLIENT (RRH) RECIEVES AND SENDS DATA TO SERVER (BBU) NEEDS TO BE FULL DUPLEX */
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (1)
    {
      //----------------------------------------- RECIEVE AUDIO DATAGRAMS
      len = PAYLOAD_SIZE;
      int playback_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd1, (void *)play_load, PAYLOAD_SIZE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr1, &len);

      //----------------------------------------- ALSA PLAYBACK DATAGRAMS
      rc = snd_pcm_writei(handle, play_load, frames);
      // if true, audio is playing
      if (rc>0 && i>0){
          printf("CLIENT: Playing audio!!!\n");
          i--;
      }
      if (rc == -EPIPE) {
          // EPIPE means underrun
          fprintf(stderr, "playback underrun occurred\n");
          snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
      } else if (rc < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "playback error from writei: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
      } else if (rc != (int)frames) {
          fprintf(stderr, "playback short write, write %d frames\n", rc);
      }

      //------------------------------------------- SEND PLAYBACK ACK
      sendto(sockfd2, ACK_play, strlen(ACK_play), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr2, len);
      printf("1 -sending audio playback ACK\n");

      //------------------------------------------- ALSA RECORDING DATAGRAMS

      /*//¡¡¡uncomment to record audio and send it to server!!!

      rc2 = snd_pcm_readi(handle2, rec_load, frames2);
      if (rc2 == -EPIPE) {
      // EPIPE means overrun
          fprintf(stderr, "recording overrun occurred\n");
          snd_pcm_prepare(handle2);
      } else if (rc2 < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "recording error from read: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc2));
      } else if (rc2 != (int)frames2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "recording short read, read %d frames\n", rc2);
      }
      //rc2 = write(1, buffer2, size2); //Only to see recorded data// Only uncomment to save recorded audio into a raw file
      if (rc2 != size2)
          fprintf(stderr, "recording short write: wrote %d bytes\n", rc2);
      */

      //------------------------------------------- SEND RECORDING DATAGRAMS
      sendto(sockfd3, MSG, strlen(MSG), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr3, len);
      //sendto(sockfd3, rec_load, PAYLOAD_SIZE, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr3, len);//uncomment to send audio recorded datagrams
      printf("2 -sending audio recording datagrams\n");

      //------------------------------------------- SEND RECORDING ACK
      sendto(sockfd4, ACK_rec, strlen(ACK_rec), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr4, len);
       printf("3 -sending audio recording ACK\n\n");

      //------------------------------------------- PLAYBACK FINISH
      if(playback_bytes<2048){
          printf("END PLAYBACK DATAGRAMS %d\n",playback_bytes);
          break;
      }

    }
    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    close(sockfd1); //close file descriptor
    close(sockfd2);
    close(sockfd3);
    close(sockfd4);
    return 0;
}
//END
```

server:

```
//COMPILE:  gcc -o server server.c
//EXECUTE: ./server < filename.wav
/*
-----Implementation Base Band Unit server side

BBU sends audio through a dedicated sockets to RRH
and recieves it throught a different socket  from it
through a dedicated socket to process it afterwards
in other modules.
*/

/* DEPENDENCIES */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
/* CONSTANTS */
#define PORT1            8070
#define PORT2            8080
#define PORT3            8090
#define PORT4            8100
#define MAXLINE          1024
#define PAYLOAD_SIZE     2048

// START
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int                 sockfd1, sockfd2, sockfd3, sockfd4;
    int                 len, len2, len3, n, ad;
    char                buffer1[MAXLINE];
    char                buffer2[MAXLINE];
    const char* msg =   "\nSERVER: Sending audio complete";
    const char* ACK =   "ack";

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr1, cliaddr1;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr2, cliaddr2;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr3, cliaddr3;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr4, cliaddr4;
    
    /*********************************************
    *     CREATING SOCKET FILE DESCRIPTOR        *
    *********************************************/

    // SOCKET 1
    if ((sockfd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        /*AL_INET: ipv4; SOCK_DGRAM: UPD; 0: default protocol*/
        perror("socket 1 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr1, 0, sizeof(servaddr1));     // Allocate memory for structure
    memset(&cliaddr1,  0, sizeof(cliaddr1));
    // Filling server information
    servaddr1.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // IPv4
    servaddr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any client
    servaddr1.sin_port =        htons(PORT1);

    // SOCKET 2
    if ((sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        /*AL_INET: ipv4; SOCK_DGRAM: UPD; 0: default protocol*/
        perror("socket 2 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr2, 0, sizeof(servaddr2));     // Allocate memory for structure
    memset(&cliaddr2,  0, sizeof(cliaddr2));
    // Filling server information
    servaddr2.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // IPv4
    servaddr2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any client
    servaddr2.sin_port =        htons(PORT2);

    // SOCKET 3
    if ((sockfd3 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        /*AL_INET: ipv4; SOCK_DGRAM: UPD; 0: default protocol*/
    perror("socket 3 creation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr3, 0, sizeof(servaddr3));     // Allocate memory for structure
    memset(&cliaddr3,  0, sizeof(cliaddr3));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr3.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // IPv4
    servaddr3.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any client
    servaddr3.sin_port =        htons(PORT3);

    // SOCKET 4
    if ((sockfd4 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        /*AL_INET: ipv4; SOCK_DGRAM: UPD; 0: default protocol*/
        perror("socket 4 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&servaddr4, 0, sizeof(servaddr4));     // Allocate memory for structure
    memset(&cliaddr4,  0, sizeof(cliaddr4));
    // Filling server information
    servaddr4.sin_family =      AF_INET;              // IPv4
    servaddr4.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;      // Any client
    servaddr4.sin_port =        htons(PORT4);

    /********************************************
    *  BIND THE SOCKET WITH THE SERVER ADDRESS  *
    ********************************************/
    //sockfd:   File descriptor of socket to be binded
    //addr:     Structure in which address to be binded to is specified
    //addrlen:  Size of addr structure

    // BIND SOCKET 1
    if (bind(sockfd1, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr1, sizeof(servaddr1)) < 0) {
        perror("bind socket 1 failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // BIND SOCKET 2
    if (bind(sockfd2, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr2, sizeof(servaddr2)) < 0) {
        perror("bind socket 2 failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // BIND SOCKET 3
    if (bind(sockfd3, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr3, sizeof(servaddr3)) < 0) {
        perror("bind socket 3 failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // BIND SOCKET 4
    if (bind(sockfd4, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr4, sizeof(servaddr4)) < 0) {
        perror("bind socket 4 failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /********************************************
    *       RECEIVE MSG FROM CLIENT             *
    /*******************************************/
    //sockfd:   file descriptor of socket
    //buffer:   Apllication buffer in which to recieve data
    //len:      Size of buffer
    //flags:    Bitwise OR flags to modify socket behaviour
    //src_addr: Structure containing source address is returned
    //addrlen:  Variable in which size of src_addr structure is returned

    len = PAYLOAD_SIZE;  // len is value/result
    printf("\nSERVER: Waiting for client connection...\n");
    n = recvfrom(sockfd1, (char *)buffer1, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr1, &len);
    buffer1[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer1);

    /********************************************
    *         SEND MSG TO CLIENT                *
    ********************************************/
    //sockfd:   File descriptor of socket
    //buffer:   Application buffer cointaining the data to be sent
    //len:      Size of buffer
    //flags:    Bitwise OR flags to modify socket behaviour
    //dest_addr:    Structure containing address of destination
    //addrlen:  Size of dest_addr structure

    // We allocate memory for the datagrams payload
    char* payload = (char*)malloc(PAYLOAD_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    printf("SERVER: Sending audio...\n");
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /* HERE SERVER (BBU) SENDS DATA TO CLIENT (RRH) NEEDS TO BE FULL DUPLEX */
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (1)
    {
        //---------------------------------------- READING AUDIO FILE
        int playback = read(0, (void*)payload, PAYLOAD_SIZE);
        if (playback <= 0){// If true, audio send end
            printf("%s\n\n", msg);
            break;
        }
        //--------------------------------------- SEND AUDIO PLAYBACK DATAGRAMS
        sendto(sockfd1, (void*)payload, playback, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr1, len);
        printf(" 1- Sending audio playback datagrams\n");

        //--------------------------------------- RECIEVE AUDIO PLAYBACK ACK
        len2 = sizeof(cliaddr2);
        n = recvfrom(sockfd2, (char *)buffer1, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr2, &len);
        buffer1[n] = '\0';
        //printf("CLIENT: %s\n", buffer1);// to check incoming ack
        printf(" 2- Receiving audio playback ACK\n");

        //--------------------------------------- RECIEVE AUDIO RECORDING DATAGRAMS
        ad = recvfrom(sockfd3, (char *)buffer2, PAYLOAD_SIZE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr3, &len);
        printf(" 3- Receiving audio recording datagrams\n");
        buffer2[ad] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buffer2);

        //--------------------------------------- RECEIVE RECORDING ACK
        n = recvfrom(sockfd4, (char *)buffer1, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr4, &len);
        buffer1[n] = '\0';
        //printf("CLIENT: %s\n", buffer1);//to check incoming ack
        printf(" 4- Receiving audio recording ACK\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
//END
```

Comment: Good luck with your question, but getting real-time audio over IP working can be complicated.

Comment: I'm already experiencing it, thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: I have some professional/commercial experience with sending/receiving realtime [broadcast quality] audio/video [H.264], but I'm not familiar with `C-RAN`. Why so many ports/sockets? Is this a _requirement_ of a/the protocol that you can't change? Or, is this simply how your code does it? I think you'd be better served with a _single_ socket. Why do you ACK? UDP is unreliable. What do you/should you do if a packet gets dropped. I see a number of issues with your code, but I'd like to get more info before I post an answer.

Comment: PART 1: As I said at the beginnig of the post, this is part of a larger code and in order to simplify the pose of the issue I have rather pose it as a simple client-server service. I need different sockets for each audio direction. Imagine users talking to their cellphones and their signals going to a certain antenna, the client is part of that antenna and the server would be a part of the base station where calls are connected and redirected again via IP through other C-RAN modules.

Comment: PART 2: Having a socket for each audio direction allows control of throughput and QoS for internal modules attached to the C-RAN chain. Why ACK, it's a way to control the throughtput for either server or client. If a packet gets lost, there's no problem it barely will be notice by the users after all the processing, imagine what a disaster would be by TCP. This is a very condensed answer in order to put you in situation.

Comment: You are transmitting just raw data. Is that a protocol requirement? Or, can you encapsulate the raw data with a meta data header that has (e.g.) a sequence number or timestamp? Without that, of course, you're going to lose packets and the timing will get skewed. The client has to detect gaps and fill in dummy samples for dropped packets, maintaining sync when audio resumes. Normally, a client will prebuffer enough data to allow for variations in arrival time of packets, at the expense of latency. How much latency can you tolerate?

Comment: PART 1: This is adpated in such a way that can be tested using simple wav files. If when recording you want to save an audio file when executing the client, then yes, you will get a raw audio data file but this is just for the sake of checking that the recorded data has been properlly recorded. If you want to try, then you only have to worry to achieve to pass an audio wav file to the client and that what ever is recording the client (ex. ur mic) is sent properlly.

Comment: PART 2: In case you want to check if what you have recorded sound fine, then pipe it to a file when executing it; i.e ./client > recorded.raw. Then you can pas that same file from the server to the client and listen.